# share image on twitter and get favourites list from iOS native app

Tags: ios, objective-c, twitter

I found many tutorials online how to share image on twitter from an iOS app. But i want to know 2 things about social sharing with twitter-

1. If i post an image on twitter via my app, Can i get image id from twitter in callback method/block? If yes then how?
2. If i fetch favourites of a user, is the response include text posted with that image? I checked for the same on twitter [Rest API doc](https://dev.twitter.com/rest/reference/get/favorites/list) that there is a `text` property returned in the response.
   Now my question is that if i post some text with image via my iOS app and later make this post favourite in twitter app and now i get my favourites list through twitter rest API in my app, does the `text` property in the response is same that i posted with my post?

**Edit about #1 above:-** from [SLComposeViewControllerResult docs](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/NetworkingInternet/Reference/SLComposeViewController_Class/index.html#//apple_ref/c/tdef/SLComposeViewControllerResult) i found that completion handler return one of

```
typedef NS_ENUM (NSInteger,
   SLComposeViewControllerResult ) {
   SLComposeViewControllerResultCancelled,
   SLComposeViewControllerResultDone 
};
```

constant so there is no info about image just posted. Am i right? If not please give me some reference about how to get image id please.

Comment: I got media id by using STTwitter

Comment: Ok, will give it a try. Do you have any idea about my 2nd problem? it is more important then media id.

Comment: Yes, you will get the same text in the response. I have edited my answer. Check that

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
Here I have customize alertView,NSLog,etc. You ignore that.
```

Here is the code to share to twitter by using STTwitter library

```
 - (void)shareToTwitter
    {
        APP_DELEGATE.navController = self.navigationController;

        NSString *strTwitterToken       = [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] objectForKey:@"TwitterToken"];
        NSString *strTwitterTokenSecret = [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] objectForKey:@"TwitterTokenSecret"];

        if (strTwitterToken && strTwitterTokenSecret)
        {
            self.twitter = [STTwitterAPI twitterAPIWithOAuthConsumerKey:TwitterConsumerKey consumerSecret:TwitterSecretKey oauthToken:strTwitterToken oauthTokenSecret:strTwitterTokenSecret];

            [self.twitter verifyCredentialsWithSuccessBlock:^(NSString *username) {
                DLogs(@"Twitter User Name");

                [self twitterMediaUpload];

            } errorBlock:^(NSError *error) {
                DLogs(@"-- error: %@", error);
                [AppConstant showAutoDismissAlertWithMessage:[error localizedDescription] onView:self.view];

                [self safariLoginTwitter];
            }];
        }

        else
        {
            [self safariLoginTwitter];
        }

    }

    -(void)safariLoginTwitter
    {
    //    [APP_CONSTANT getNativeTwitterAccountAccessToken:^(id result) {
    //        
    //    }];

        self.twitter = [STTwitterAPI twitterAPIWithOAuthConsumerKey:TwitterConsumerKey
                                                     consumerSecret:TwitterSecretKey];

        [self.twitter postTokenRequest:^(NSURL *url, NSString *oauthToken) {
            DLogs(@"-- url: %@", url);
            DLogs(@"-- oauthToken: %@", oauthToken);

            [[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:url];
        } authenticateInsteadOfAuthorize:NO
                            forceLogin:@(YES)
                            screenName:nil
                         oauthCallback:@"myapp://twitter_access_tokens/"
                            errorBlock:^(NSError *error) {
                                DLogs(@"-- error: %@", error);
                                [AppConstant showAutoDismissAlertWithMessage:[error localizedDescription] onView:self.view];
                            }];
    }

    - (void)setOAuthToken:(NSString *)token oauthVerifier:(NSString *)verifier {

        [self.twitter postAccessTokenRequestWithPIN:verifier successBlock:^(NSString *oauthToken, NSString *oauthTokenSecret, NSString *userID, NSString *screenName) {
            DLogs(@"-- screenName: %@", screenName);

            /*
             At this point, the user can use the API and you can read his access tokens with:

             _twitter.oauthAccessToken;
             _twitter.oauthAccessTokenSecret;

             You can store these tokens (in user default, or in keychain) so that the user doesn't need to authenticate again on next launches.

             Next time, just instanciate STTwitter with the class method:

             +[STTwitterAPI twitterAPIWithOAuthConsumerKey:consumerSecret:oauthToken:oauthTokenSecret:]

             Don't forget to call the -[STTwitter verifyCredentialsWithSuccessBlock:errorBlock:] after that.
             */

            [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setObject:self.twitter.oauthAccessToken forKey:@"TwitterToken"];
            [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setObject:self.twitter.oauthAccessToken forKey:@"TwitterTokenSecret"];
            [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] synchronize];

            [self twitterMediaUpload];

        } errorBlock:^(NSError *error) {

            [AppConstant showAutoDismissAlertWithMessage:[error localizedDescription] onView:self.view];
            DLogs(@"-- %@", [error localizedDescription]);
        }];
    }

    -(void)twitterMediaUpload
    {
        //    ProfileImageBO *objProfImg = nil;
        //
        //    if ([self.objProfile.arrUserImages count]) {
        //        objProfImg = [self.objProfile.arrUserImages objectAtIndex:0];
        //    }

        [APP_CONSTANT showLoaderWithTitle:@"posting" onView:self.view];

        //    NSURL *urlProfImg = [NSURL URLWithString:[objProfImg.imageUrl stringByAddingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];

        NSURL *screenshotUrl = [self getScreenshotUrl];

        [self.twitter postMediaUpload:screenshotUrl uploadProgressBlock:^(NSInteger bytesWritten, NSInteger totalBytesWritten, NSInteger totalBytesExpectedToWrite) {
            DLogs(@"uploading");
        } successBlock:^(NSDictionary *imageDictionary, NSString *mediaID, NSString *size) {
            DLogs(@"imageDictionary =  %@, mediaID = %@, size %@",imageDictionary.description,mediaID,size);

            [self postToTheTwitterWithMediaId:mediaID];

        } errorBlock:^(NSError *error) {
            DLogs(@"Error in uploading media, try again ...");

            [APP_CONSTANT hideLoader];
            [AppConstant showAutoDismissAlertWithMessage:error.localizedDescription onView:self.view];
        }];
    }

    -(void)postToTheTwitterWithMediaId:(NSString *)mediaID
    {
        NSString *msg = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Check out My Profile"];

        [self.twitter postStatusUpdate:msg inReplyToStatusID:nil mediaIDs:[NSArray arrayWithObject:mediaID] latitude:nil longitude:nil placeID:nil displayCoordinates:nil trimUser:nil successBlock:^(NSDictionary *status) {
            DLogs(@"Description %@",status.description);

            [self showNotificationToastWithMessage:TwitterPostSuccess];
            [APP_CONSTANT hideLoader];

        } errorBlock:^(NSError *error) {
            DLogs(@"Twitter posting error %@",error.description);
            [APP_CONSTANT hideLoader];

            [AppConstant showAutoDismissAlertWithMessage:error.localizedDescription onView:self.view];
        }];

    }
```

For your second question: Yes, you will get the same text in the response
And This is the code to get favorite list

```
-(void)getFavListTwitter
{
    [self.twitter getFavoritesListWithSuccessBlock:^(NSArray *statuses) {
        DLogs(@"%@",statuses.description);
    } errorBlock:^(NSError *error) {
        DLogs(@"%@",error.description);
    }];
}
```